# getting an error while executing an sqlQuery containing in clause

Tags: java, mysql

I have an sqlQuery:

```
select * from products where product_type in :prodTypes
query.setParameter("prodTypes",getInClauseFromList(productTypes));
```

productTypes is a `List<String>`

```
public String getInClauseFromList(List list) {
    if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
      String inClause = Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
      inClause = inClause.replace("[", "('").replace("]", "')");
      inClause = inClause.replace(", ", "','");
      return inClause;
    }
    return "('')";
  }
```

I get an error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near ''(\'clothes\')')
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you and us if you could also show us what the actual text of the query is.  Right now, I think we could only speculate about the exact syntax error.

Comment: I tried the show sql:
I get select * from products where product_type in ?
It's not helpful :(

Comment: I need to see the `IN` clause as plain text.  There is some small problem, but we need to see this.

Comment: OK...but this is a bit like throwing out the baby with the bathwater.  My advice to you is to print to console or log the result from `getInClauseFromList()`.  It will be obvious why MySQL is barfing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using something like Spring's JDBCTemplate. Then you don't have to convert the list manually to a String.

In your example above the String you are passing in is quoted (as it should be) and hence the resulting SQL is not correct.

Given that I don't know which type "query" is: Try setting the list directly as the parameter. Most of the frameworks should support converting it properly for the IN clause.